# nth term test for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{1/n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

the n-th term test for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty  }{1/n}$ implies that the series converges
since $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n =0$
but the series actually diverges. what is the error in the procedure followed?

Comment: Do you actually mean $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty  }{1/i}$?

Comment: yes @Bernard , i edited it

Comment: What's the n-th term test?

Comment: This is only a necessary, not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converse of nth term test for divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447547/converse-of-nth-term-test-for-divergence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful: the theorem states

> If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=0$

which conversely means

> If $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}\neq 0$ then $\sum a_n$ does not converge.

This means that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=0$ is a necessary **but not sufficient** condition for a series to converge.

Answer (score 1):

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, than limit of $n$-th term $a_n$ is zero as $n\to\infty$. It's because convergence means existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$, where $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$,
and $a_n = S_{n} - S_{n-1}$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =
\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n - \lim_{n\to\infty} S_{n-1} = 0$ as latter two limits are equal. However, converse isn’t true as your example shows.